# What is the different between the I-TASSER, phyre2, SWISS-model in the 3D tertiary structure?

Tags: sequence-alignment, proteins, protein-structure, sequence-analysis, 3d-structure

What is the difference between the I-TASSER, phyre2, and SWISS-model in the 3D tertiary structure?

How do they get the results? When I did a prediction, I got a similar result for the highest template in I-TASSER and Swiss, while it was different with Phyre2. What does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

This is a common Q.

Briefly, you have some techniques here that get used separately or combined:

- Ab initio: assemble the protein from scratch, often via a library fragmented peptides (3-mer, 6-mers, 9-mers) based on real structures.
- Template threading: given a protein structure alter it to make it like a give sequence. SWISS-MODEL, Rosetta's SimpleThreadingMover, ModBase, Phyre template threading etc. This is why some of these keep ligands and deal well with multimers. For missing loops in the template these are filled by ab initio methods.
- Hybridisation: give a bunch of models mix and match them for the best energy. I-Tasser, RosettaCM (which uses SimpleThreadingMover), Phyre (which uses Phyre template threading)
- Ab initio with contraints, such as evolutionary covariance. EVFold, AlphaFold2, trRosetta. Often mixed with template based approaches.

Wikipedia has more, but papers are very helpful despite the car-salesmanship.

One thing to note is that protein can adopt different conformations. The AlphaFold2/ColabFold notebooks give multiple models: these may be legit alt conformations, e.g. inactive vs active etc etc

Here is a SwissModel vs AF2:
[Different structures of same protein from two softwares](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/17854/different-structures-of-same-protein-from-two-softwares/17857#17857)

Other helpful As:

- [How to make 3d model of a protein that not exist in PDB?](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/16169/how-to-make-3d-model-of-a-protein-that-not-exist-in-pdb/16170#16170)
- [Phyre2 vs ITasser, completely different models generated](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/159/phyre2-vs-itasser-completely-different-models-generated)
- [How reliable is Alphafold2 for folding random-coil peptide](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/18894/how-reliable-is-alphafold2-for-folding-random-coil-peptide) —discussion of technical details going wrong... Personally, I had Phyre2 made an alignment mistake which altered the protein